# Multiple Primary key while migrating | Django Models

Tags: django

Even i have made only one primary key.I don't know why it says error as multiple primary key when I migrate the changes.

```
class Userinfo(models.Model):
    ''' User info ''' 
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=False,primary_key=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,primary_key=False)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_rename, blank=True)
```

Migrations

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('userinfo', '0012_delete_authdetails'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='userinfo',
            name='user_name',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True),
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='userinfo',
            name='id',
        )

    ]
```

Can some help with this ??

Comment: What's the current definition? Do you get the error with `makemigrations`or `migrate`? If the latter, can you also post the migration script that `makemigrations` creates.

Comment: i have added the migration script

Comment: I think you're likely to have to do this in more than one step, possibly even edit the migration files. Alternatively you could dump all the existing data to json /yaml using `dumpdata`, recreate your table with the new key structure and load the data again using `loaddata`.  THe latter is probably simpler, and I'm not sure if the former is even possible ...

Comment: I did find this old post about changing pks ... you could try this apporoach, but it is an old one - don't see anything that wouldn't work in Django 2 or 3 though ... https://blog.hexack.fr/en/change-the-primary-key-of-a-django-model.html

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```html
class Userinfo(models.Model):
    ''' User info ''' 
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=False,primary_key=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_rename, blank=True)
```

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any differences between this and the original code???

Comment: there was a change in email field where i was assigning primary key as false because  I thought that it could be possible that email field was default primary key